# How to access value of radio button in form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button, form-for

I work with Ruby on Rails. I want the user to search for images, select one of the results, and use the url as a parameter for creating a resource.

Here's my code: [Code](https://gist.github.com/SilverSilence/0fe5a5b33a391a4fdd4c)

In `groups_show.rb`, line 55, that's where I would like `image` to have the value of the checked radio button, but I don't know how to access it.

Comment: You should add JavaScript code on view side, when user selects an image, use JavaScript to set the image's url to your form.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do that? I barely know any javascript or jquery.